# adding install location in installdir to Registry key in installshield 2018

Tags: wix, windows-installer, registry, installshield

I do not know how I can put the user-selected installation path in the registry key in the Installshield environment. Please guide me step by step.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Essence***: Essentially storing property values in the registry entails explicitly defining them to be written into a known registry location (I use per-machine, in other words HKLM, to ensure the property can be read back by all users on the machine) and then you use **AppSearch** (built-in MSI mechanism) or a **custom action** to read back the values as appropriate.

```
HKLM\Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\[ProductVersion] = [PROPERTYNAME]
```

***How-To***: Rather than me repeating the steps here, please read the following documents:

- [InstallShield Tip: Saving MSI property values to make them available after the initial installation](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/MsiPropUninst.pdf)
- [The WiX toolset's "Remember Property" pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/)

***Complexity***: The latter link is not for Installshield, but for WiX. It shows the same save property procedure in WiX, but more importantly it discusses how reading properties back from the registry can conflict with properties set on the command line.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)